# WPA_GUI "the configuration could not be saved"

Tags: raspbian, wireless, gui, wpa

I'm trying to setup WiFi on my RaspberryPi running Raspbian. WPI_GUI refuses to allow my to save it's configuration as

> The configuration could not be saved. The update_config=1
> configuration option must be used for configuration saving to be
> permitted

This is strange, as the contents of my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf contain:

> ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
>
> update_config=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and add the line

```
        disabled=1
```

below each

```
        ssid="..."
```

line.
Save the file and reboot, I had a similar problem (could not edit bad settings) and it allowed me to edit the settings again after the reboot.

In my case though the problem was an incorrectly configured wireless, it seemed to get stuck in a dead loop of trying to connect and would not let me use the GUI to correct the problem!

Comment: Hah nice one! :D

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar message recently. For me I had to add

`update_config=1`

to the top of the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file. Got a write error warning once but new Wifi configurations now save properly.

Comment: But this is set by default so normally there is no need to set it.